# Json functions working in mysql version 5.7 and mariadb 10.4.11 but not in 10.1.44

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, mariadb

I had a strange problem where any kind of json commands were not working after i had uploaded my project in the server where mysql version was 5.6. In my localhost my server version was 10.4.11 and the query was working fine.  I checked it has to be at least 5.7. So i checked the query in 5.7 also which was working fine. Then I updated my server and to 10.1.44. But now the query was not working

The error is:

> Syntax error or access violation 1305.function dbname.json_contains does not exist

and here is one my query below where I was using laravel

```
Card::SELECT('id','name','unique_id')
    ->where(DB::raw("json_extract(present_address, '$.union')"), 'some_union')
    ->where('geo_union_id','=',2218)
    ->get();
```

Could you please give me a solution for this? And if there is any documentation of how I would be able to use this function in mariadb 10.1.44 then please do let me know about it

Comment: JSON Functions in mariaDB were introduced in V10.2.3. Simple google

Comment: ok so  it is working in 5.7 or higher but not in mariadb 10.1.44. if i just update the version upper then what u have suggested, it should work.???

Comment: Yes, mariaDB should work with version 10.2.3 or greater. Please remember 5.7 is a MySQL version number. MySQL and mariaDB started off almost exactly the same but as time passes they are getting more and more different

Answer (score 0):

According to mariadb offical page in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

*The JSON alias was added in MariaDB 10.2.7.*

So if you want to use json functions in your query you must be use **10.2.7 or higher versions** of mariadb. If you can not this, just use `LONGTEXT` and search with `regex` in `where` clause